# Simulating sql query in tableau desktop

Tags: tableau-api

This is my sql query.

```
select id,Achtivation_date,max(Transaxtion_date),Customer_points,count(Transaction-id) from table1
left join tableb b on a.id=b.id
group by id,Achtivation_date,Customer_points
```

I need to simulate this in tableau to get the results similar to this query:

[sample workbook to test](https://public.tableausoftware.com/profile/vijay123#!/vizhome/Book2_7762/Sheet1)

out of this workbook i need this result.

```
id  ahctivation transaxtion

1 20140102 20140103 2

2  20140303 20140109 3
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you want the third column of the result to represent (I guessed the first transaction time for that activation). I also am guessing that you want the last column to represent the number of rows for each id/activation pair (ignoring transaction ids).

Given those assumptions, here is a [revised workbook](https://public.tableausoftware.com/views/Response_To_StackOverflow_Question/Sheet1?:embed=y&:display_count=no) showing you two ways to get that result depending on whether you really want that third column or not.

There is nothing terribly complex here, other than perhaps treating the transaction field as a discrete measure with the MIN() aggregation function applied instead of treating it as a dimension.

Finally, although you can type custom SQL in a Tableau data connection, and sometimes need to, you can usually get the same effect more easily (and sometimes more efficiently) by just selecting and joining tables via the Tableau data connection interface. I didn't see anything in your query that requires custom SQL in Tableau, so save custom SQL for when you need it.